# Get percentage change in last 12(changeable) months for each id in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a dataset like this for each ID;

| Months | ID | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | 1 | 5240.0 |
| 2020-11-01 | 1 | 4532.0 |
| 2020-10-01 | 1 | 4532.0 |
| 2020-09-01 | 1 | 4532.0 |
| 2020-08-01 | 1 | 4532.0 |
| 2020-07-01 | 1 | 4532.0 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 | 4532.0 |
| 2020-05-01 | 1 | 4532.0 |
| 2020-04-01 | 1 | 4532.0 |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 | 4532.0 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | 3808.0 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 3808.0 |
| 2019-12-01 | 1 | 3808.0 |
| 2019-11-01 | 1 | 3808.0 |
| 2019-10-01 | 1 | 3808.0 |
| 2019-09-01 | 1 | 3808.0 |
| 2019-08-01 | 1 | 3808.0 |
| 2019-07-01 | 1 | 3808.0 |
| 2019-06-01 | 1 | 3808.0 |
| 2019-05-01 | 1 | 3808.0 |
| 2019-04-01 | 1 | 3096.0 |
| 2019-03-01 | 1 | 3096.0 |
| 2019-02-01 | 1 | 3096.0 |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 | 3096.0 |
| 2018-12-01 | 1 | 3096.0 |
| 2018-11-01 | 1 | 3096.0 |
| 2018-10-01 | 1 | 3096.0 |
| 2018-09-01 | 1 | 2669.0 |
| 2018-08-01 | 1 | 2669.0 |
| 2018-07-01 | 1 | 2669.0 |
| 2020-12-01 | 2 | 1632.0 |
| 2020-11-01 | 2 | 1632.0 |
| 2020-10-01 | 2 | 1632.0 |
| 2020-09-01 | 2 | 1600.0 |

I want to find percentage of salary change in last month, in last 6 month and in last 12 month for each id.
I used the code below;

```
    unique_all['SalaryDifferencewithLastMonth%'] = (unique_all.groupby(['ID'])['Salary'].pct_change(-1).fillna(0))
    unique_all['SalaryDifferenceinLast6Months%'] = (unique_all.groupby(['ID'])['Salary'].pct_change(-6).fillna(0))
    unique_all['SalaryDifferenceinLast12Months%'] = (unique_all.groupby(['ID'])['Salary'].pct_change(-12).fillna(0))
```

And i got that dataset;

| Months | ID | Salary | SalaryDifferencewithLastMonth% | SalaryDifferenceinLast6Months% | SalaryDifferenceinLast12Months% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | 1 | 5240.0 | 0.156222 | 0.156222 | 0.376050 |
| 2020-11-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-10-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-09-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-08-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-07-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-05-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-04-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 | 0.463824 |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.190126 | 0.190126 | 0.463824 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 |
| 2019-12-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 |
| 2019-11-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 |
| 2019-10-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 | 0.229974 |
| 2019-09-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 | 0.426752 |
| 2019-08-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 | 0.426752 |
| 2019-07-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 | 0.426752 |
| 2019-06-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 | 0.000000 |
| 2019-05-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.229974 | 0.229974 | 0.000000 |
| 2019-04-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2019-03-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.159985 | 0.000000 |
| 2019-02-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.159985 | 0.000000 |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.159985 | 0.000000 |
| 2018-12-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2018-11-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2018-10-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.159985 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2018-09-01 | 1 | 2669.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2018-08-01 | 1 | 2669.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2018-07-01 | 1 | 2669.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2020-12-01 | 2 | 1632.0 | 0.00 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 2020-11-01 | 2 | 1632.0 | 0.00 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 2020-10-01 | 2 | 1632.0 | 0.02 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 2020-09-01 | 2 | 1600.0 | 0.00 | 0.0 | 0.0 |

It works fine for those with data but not good for remaining rows. If ID has no data for 12 months and there is a change in the last 6 months, it returns the value, but for the last 12 months, it returns 0. I want 12 months to cover 6 months. So if it can't go back 12 months, i want it to go to last month of the ID and find the change with that month's salary.

I want a dataset like this;

| Months | ID | Salary | SalaryDifferencewithLastMonth% | SalaryDifferenceinLast6Months% | SalaryDifferenceinLast12Months% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | 1 | 5240.0 | 0.156222 | 0.156222 | 0.376050 |
| 2020-11-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-10-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-09-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-08-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-07-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-05-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 | 0.190126 |
| 2020-04-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.000000 | 0.190126 | 0.463824 |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 | 4532.0 | 0.190126 | 0.190126 | 0.463824 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 |
| 2019-12-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 |
| 2019-11-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 |
| 2019-10-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 | 0.229974 |
| 2019-09-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 | 0.426752 |
| 2019-08-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 | 0.426752 |
| 2019-07-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 | 0.426752 |
| 2019-06-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.000000 | 0.229974 | 0.426752 |
| 2019-05-01 | 1 | 3808.0 | 0.229974 | 0.229974 | 0.426752 |
| 2019-04-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.159985 |
| 2019-03-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.159985 | 0.159985 |
| 2019-02-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.159985 | 0.159985 |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.159985 | 0.159985 |
| 2018-12-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.159985 | 0.159985 |
| 2018-11-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.000000 | 0.159985 | 0.159985 |
| 2018-10-01 | 1 | 3096.0 | 0.159985 | 0.159985 | 0.159985 |
| 2018-09-01 | 1 | 2669.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2018-08-01 | 1 | 2669.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2018-07-01 | 1 | 2669.0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2020-12-01 | 2 | 1632.0 | 0.00 | 0.02 | 0.02 |
| 2020-11-01 | 2 | 1632.0 | 0.00 | 0.02 | 0.02 |
| 2020-10-01 | 2 | 1632.0 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.02 |
| 2020-09-01 | 2 | 1600.0 | 0.00 | 0.0 | 0.0 |

If there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a better solution, but for now I used a method like this.

```
    #Find the percentage changes, but it remains Nan for the last months.

    unique_all['SalaryDifferencewithLastMonth%'] = (unique_all.groupby(['ID'])['Salary'].pct_change(-1))
    unique_all['SalaryDifferenceinLast6Months%'] = (unique_all.groupby(['ID'])['Salary'].pct_change(-6))
    unique_all['SalaryDifferenceinLast12Months%'] = (unique_all.groupby(['ID'])['Salary'].pct_change(-12))

    #Find the salary of the latest month(at the bottom) for each id

    latest_salary = pd.DataFrame(unique_all.loc[unique_all.groupby('ID').Months.idxmin()][['ID','Salary']].reset_index(drop=True))
    latest_salary = latest_salary.rename(columns={'Salary':'latest_salary'})
    unique_all= unique_all.merge(latest_salary,on='ID',how='left')
    
    #Find the percentage change with the latest month of the id and assign to the Nan values

    unique_all['salary_diff2'] = ((unique_all['Salary'] - unique_all['latest_salary']) * 100 / unique_all['latest_salary']) / 100

    unique_all['SalaryDifferenceinLast12Months%'] = unique_all['SalaryDifferenceinLast12Months%'].fillna(unique_all['salary_diff2'].loc[unique_all['SalaryDifferenceinLast12Months%'].isnull()]) 
    unique_all['SalaryDifferenceinLast6Months%'] = unique_all['SalaryDifferenceinLast6Months%'].fillna(unique_all['salary_diff2'].loc[unique_all['SalaryDifferenceinLast6Months%'].isnull()]) 
    unique_all['SalaryDifferencewithLastMonth%'] = unique_all['SalaryDifferencewithLastMonth%'].fillna(unique_all['salary_diff2'].loc[unique_all['SalaryDifferencewithLastMonth%'].isnull()])
```